# How to I keep my Magic Trackpad safe in transit?

Tags: magic-trackpad

My magic trackpad keeps getting knocked around in my bag and I feel like protecting it more. What are some good options for a case/sleeve for it?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google, I found a few:

- [WaterField](http://www.sfbags.com/products/apple-magic-trackpad-slip)
- [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005VCYPUI) *I realize the manufacturer isn't amazon*

Comment: Or just use a washcloth :-)